# If Java people go to Scala, C# go to F#, where do Ruby people go for functional nirvana?

Tags: ruby, scala, f#, functional-programming, paradigms

I know a lot of Java people have started looking at Scala since it runs on the JVM, and a lot of people in the Microsoft world are looking at F#, but what does Ruby have as a natural functional successor?

In a pure FP sense Ruby doesn't lack anything, instead it has too much some may say. A functional language forces the programmer to not use global variables and other idioms so much (although it is possible to use globals in functional languages)

Comment: What FP functionality Ruby lacks so that it would need any "functional successor" whatsoever?

Comment: I guess something that runs as a nice "distributed" functional language is something Ruby lacks. Also, in a pure FP sense you are right in that Ruby doesn't lack anything, instead it has too much. A functional language forces the programmer to not use global variables so much (although it is possible)

Comment: @Zubair, yes that's about how I feel.. Ruby is designed as the multi-paradigm language though. You can program in it for about any paradigm you want.. Though you can't escape from OOP very easily with it.

Comment: Take a close look at any substantial application written in a functional language, and you will find global variables there, too.  For perspective on this from someone who has been there and done that, see: http://prog21.dadgum.com/3.html .  Be sure to look at his other articles about functional programming, too.

Comment: Interesting article Wayne, I never thought of using Erlang for writing games. Thanks

Comment: I would use word "companion" rather than "successor".

Answer (score 76, accepted):

There's two *very* different definitions of what "functional programming" means. You can kind-of do the one in Ruby, but you cannot do the other.

Those two definitions are:

- programming with first-class functions and
- programming with mathematical functions

You can kind-of program with first-class functions in Ruby. It has support for first-class functions. In fact, it has *too much* support for them: there is `Proc.new`, `proc`, `lambda`, `Method`, `UnboundMethod`, blocks, `#to_proc` and `->()` (and probably some others that I forget).

All of these [behave slightly differently](http://Innig.Net/software/ruby/closures-in-ruby.rb), have slightly different syntax, slightly different behavior and slightly different restrictions. For example: the only one of these which is syntactically lightweight enough that you can actually use it densely, is blocks. But blocks have some rather severe restrictions: you can only pass one block to a method, blocks aren't objects (which in an object-oriented language in wich "everything is an object" is a *very* severe restriction) and at least in Ruby 1.8 there are also some restrictions w.r.t parameters.

Referring to a method is another thing that is fairly awkward. In [Python](http://Python.Org/) or [ECMAScript](http://ECMAScript.Org/) for example, I can just say `baz = foo.bar` to refer to the `bar` method of the `foo` object. In Ruby, `foo.bar` is a method *call*, if I want to refer to the `bar` method of `foo`, I have to say `baz = foo.method(:bar)`. And if I now want to *call* that method, I cannot just say `baz()`, I have to say `baz.call` or `baz[]` or (in Ruby 1.9) `baz.()`.

So, first-class functions in Ruby aren't *really* first-class. They are much better than second-class, and they are *good enough*™, but they aren't fully first-class.

But generally, Rubyists do not leave Ruby just for first-class functions. Ruby's support is good enough that any advantages you might gain from better support in another language usually is eaten up by the training effort for the new language or by something *else* that you are accustomed to that you must now give up. Like, say RubyGems or tight Unix integration or Ruby on Rails or syntax or …

However, the *second* definition of FP is where Ruby falls flat on its face. If you want to do programming with mathematical functions in Ruby, you are in for a world of pain. You cannot use the absolute majority of Ruby libraries, because most of them are stateful, effectful, encourage mutation or are otherwise impure. You cannot use the standard library for the same reasons. You cannot use the core library. You cannot use any of the core datatypes, because they are all mutable. You could just say "I don't care that they are mutable, I will simply not mutate them and always copy them", but the problem is: someone else still can mutate them. Also, because they are mutable, Ruby cannot optimize the copying and the garbage collector isn't tuned for that kind of workload.

It just doesn't work.

There is also a couple of features that have really nothing to do with functional programming but that most functional languages tend to have, that Ruby is missing. Pattern matching, for example. Laziness also was not that easy to achieve before `Enumerator`s were more aggressively used in Ruby 1.9. And there's still some stuff that works with strict `Enumerable`s or `Array`s but not with lazy `Enumerator`s, although there's actually no reason for them to *require* strictness.

And for *this* definition of FP, it definitely makes sense to leave Ruby behind.

The two main languages that Rubyists have been flocking to, are [Erlang](http://Erlang.Org/) and [Clojure](http://Clojure.Org/). These are both relatively good matches for Ruby, because they are both dynamically typed, have a similar REPL culture as Ruby, and (this is more a Rails thing than a Ruby thing) are also very good on the web. They have still pretty small and welcoming communities, the original language creators are still active in the community, there is a strong focus on doing new, exciting and edgy things, all of which are traits that the Ruby community also has.

The interest in Erlang started, when someone showed the original 1993 introduction video "[Erlang: The Movie](http://Archive.Org/details/ErlangTheMovie/)" at RubyConf 2006. A couple of high-profile Rails projects started using Erlang, for example [PowerSet](http://Powerset.Com/) and [GitHub](https://GitHub.Com/). Erlang is also easy to master for Rubyists, because it doesn't take purity quite as far as [Haskell](http://Haskell.Org/) or [Clean](http://Clean.CS.RU.Nl/). The *inside* of an actor is pretty pure, but the act of sending messages itself is of course a side-effect. Another thing that makes Erlang easy to grasp, is that Actors and Objects are actually the same thing, when you follow [Alan Kay's definition of object-oriented programming](http://Lists.SqueakFoundation.Org/pipermail/squeak-dev/1998-October/017019.html).

Clojure has been a recent addition to the Rubyist's toolbelt. Its popularity is I guess mostly driven by the fact that the Ruby community has finally warmed up to the idea that JVM ≠ Java and embraced [JRuby](http://JRuby.Org/) and then they started to look around what *other* interesting stuff there was on the JVM. And again, Clojure is much more pragmatic than both other functional languages like Haskell and other Lisps like [Scheme](http://Scheme-Reports.Org/) and much simpler and more modern than CommonLisp, so it is a natural fit for Rubyists.

Another cool thing about Clojure is that because both Clojure and Ruby run on the JVM, you can *combine* them.

The author of "[Programming Clojure](http://PragProg.Com/titles/shcloj/programming-clojure/)" (Stuart Halloway) is a (former?) Rubyist, for example, as is [Phil Hagelberg](http://Technomancy.us/), the author of the [Leiningen](https://GitHub.Com/Technomancy/Leiningen/) build tool for Clojure.

However, Rubyists are also looking at both [Scala](http://Scala-Lang.Org/) (as one of the more pragmatic statically typed FP languages) and Haskell (as one of the more elegant ones). Then there is projects like [Scuby](https://GitHub.Com/MCamou/Scuby/) and [Hubris](https://GitHub.Com/MWotton/Hubris/) which are bridges that let you integrate Ruby with Scala and Haskell, respectively. Twitter's decision to move part of their low-level messaging infrastructure first from MySQL to Ruby, then from Ruby to Scala is also pretty widely known.

[F#](http://FSharp.Net/) doesn't seem to play any role at all, possibly due to an irrational fear towards all things Microsoft the Ruby community has. (Which, BTW, seems mostly unfounded, given that the F# team has *always* made versions available for Mono.)

Comment: This is an amazing response -- I'm glad to see someone touching on the idea that functional programming is about more than just language constructs like closures and first-class functions. Whenever I hear people say that "Ruby is functional enough" I cringe a bit -- as your second bullet item notes, functional programming is more about a style and methodology than specific language features.

Comment: Great answer. And to back up your suggestion of Erlang as a FP language Rubyists like: The creators of Ruby On Rails, 37signals, blogged a while back about how they had rewritten part of their apps in Erlang to get better performance.

Comment: It depends. The term "functional programming" was invented for Lisp, which is very much impure, stateful, effectful, imperative or whatever you want to call it. (Except for Scheme and Clojure, both of which didn't exist yet when the term was invented.) The most widely used Lisp is CommonLisp, which isn't functional *at all* according to the mathematical definition of "function". People have proposed to call the second category "value-oriented programming" or "pure functional programming" to clear up the confusion. Martin Odersky (designer of Scala) calls them the "inclusive" and "exclusive"

Comment: ... definitions, because the first one *includes* a lot of languages, even ones that are usually *not* considered functional (like Ruby), while the second one *excludes* a lot of languages that *are* usually considered functional, like ML, OCaml, Scala, F#, Erlang and Lisp. Proponents of the second definition also often include things like pattern matching, higher-rank parametric polymorphism, astract datatypes, algebraic datatypes, powerful expressive static type systems and type inference, currying, partial functions in their definition, which excludes even *more* languages.

Comment: Lisp does not force functional programming as strongly as other languages, but it still does a lot more to enable it than most languages, and certainly more than Ruby. And though Common Lisp is more popular, it's generally considered a hybrid language, while Scheme is more strongly functional. Anyway, Lisp is quite old. C was once considered a high-level language too, but that doesn't make it a paragon of that philosophy.

Comment: Jörg, thank you for your detailed response, probably the best to any quesiton I have asked on StackOverflow yet. I learnt alot from it.

Comment: Is "strict" synonymous with "eager"?

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I never quite understood what the relationship between strictness and eager evaluation is. I *think* the latter is an implementation of the former. Not sure. Here's a quote from [Strict Programming Language (Wikipedia)](http://Wikipedia.Org/wiki/Strict_programming_language): *Strict programming languages are often associated with eager evaluation, and non-strict languages with lazy evaluation, but other evaluation strategies are possible in each case.*

Comment: Blocks *are* objects in ruby.  When you capture them, they are of class Proc (and behanve the same as Proc.new or proc)

Answer (score 14):

Java people are using a language on the JVM and want a more functional one compatible with their runtime, so they go to Scala.

C# people are using a language on the CLR and want a more functional one compatible with their runtime, so they go to F#.

Ruby people are using a language that's already pretty functional, and they're using it on a number of underlying runtimes (JRuby, IronRuby, MRI, MacRuby, Rubinius, etc...).  I don't think it has a natural functional successor, or even needs one.

Answer (score 7):

Any version of Lisp should be fine.

Comment: -1: The question isn't "what functional programming language should I use?", it's asking "what language do rubyists tend to use?"

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, but the question is (and I quote the original): "what does Ruby have as a natural functional successor?" not "what language do rubyists tend to use?".

Answer (score 6):

Ruby it self is a kind of Functional programming language, So I don't see any special dialects for FP using ruby.

Comment: It's a kind of functional programming language in much the same way that a scratch-and-sniff sticker is a kind of fruit. The hallmark of functional programming is being free of side-effects. Ruby is one of the hardest languages (if not the hardest) to write truly functional code in. Just creating a truly immutable data structure is nigh impossible in Ruby (even Fixnums can have mutable attributes added to them). Also, writing lots of true functions (that is, lambda functions rather than methods) is unidiomatic in Ruby, and functions have to be constantly converted between Procs and blocks.

Comment: See http://yellowlab.com.au/blog/2009/09/15/functional-programming-in-ruby/  Ruby doesn't really cut it in regard to FP.

Answer (score 3):

In hype level, Haskell.

Comment: I've seen Haskell, and think it is a beautiful language, and its Type system, Monads and Software Transactional Memory are amazing. I'm not sure how good it is for distributed systems though, I need educating on that still.

Comment: Typeclasses are especially nice if you're used to ruby mixins.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby isn't as functional as say Lisp, but it is just functional enough that you can do some functional programming in a good fun way. (unlike trying to do functional programming in something like C#)

Also, it actually forces you into functional paradigms in some of its syntax, such as the heavy use of blocks and yield. (which I fell in love with after learning Ruby).

Comment: Why can't you do functional programming in C# so easily (just for my personal knowledge, please don't start a flame war anyone!)?

Comment: Sure, it's possible.. C# even has stuff like lambda and anonymous functions.. But really, it's fugly and the C# API for .Net is geared for non-functional coding. Sure you can fit a round peg in a square hole, but it makes more sense to use a square peg or an almost square(ie, ruby) peg

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. But doesn't F# that use the same .NET runtime as C#?

Comment: F# has a library of core functional data types and algorithms, as well as type inference and various syntactic niceties that make it much more pleasant to do FP in F# compared to C#.  You still hit some impedence mismatch with various .Net APIs that are more imperative/OO, but these typically happen at the fringes of your F# app/library, rather than in the heart of what you're doing.

Comment: Interesting. I'll have to look into F# some more.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Ruby people don't just go to the JVM themselves, I think most would adopt Erlang, being another dynamically typed language.

Comment: Yes, I have seen alot of Ruby people move to Erlang.