# Which functional(ish) language is preferred by Rubyists

Tags: ruby, programming-languages, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [If Java people go to Scala, C# go to F#, where do Ruby people go for functional nirvana?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254368/if-java-people-go-to-scala-c-go-to-f-where-do-ruby-people-go-for-functional-n)

This is a broad question to Rubyists. What functional language (i.e. something that encourages/enforces functionalness) is most closely aligned with Ruby ideals of readability, testing, and refactoring?

Why? I just wanna try writing some stuff in functional ways to exercise new modes of thinking. 
Among Ruby friends I've heard of Scala, Clojure, Lisp, Haskell. Which is most friendly to the ruby sensibilities?

Comment: this should be a community wiki, otherwise it might get closed as 'argumentative'

Comment: @Pablo Fernandez: Actually, nowadays, questions like this should probably go to [Programmers.SE](http://Programmers.StackExchange.Com/) instead of StackOverflow. However, I'm not voting to migrate there, rather I'm voting to close as a duplicate of [If Java people go to Scala, C# go to F#, where do Ruby people go for functional nirvana?](http://StackOverflow.Com/q/2254368/#2255263). Not to forget that the old community wiki doesn't even exist anymore. You can't make a question CW, it simply becomes automatically CW, based on activity.

Comment: OMG I need to check in more often here :). Thanks @Jorg

Comment: @Jorg W Mittag: Because getting fewer than 50 upvotes on an answer isn't good enough for you! ;)

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: That's a nice ... wait for it ... *side-effect*. (Bad Pun Intended!)

Comment: @Jörg http://instantyeah.org/